# Running VirtualBox on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

The VirtualBox website says its product is for x86 hardware. My PC is Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. Will VirtualBox x86 run on my machine, and if so, would I also have to run a 32-bit version of Linux within VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes.  It does...  Did you think of just downloading it and trying it?

Comment: **ALL** 64-bit processors are x86 processors, in the context on any system that VirtualBox runs on of course l.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will be fine running Linux on Virtual Box on a 64 bit Windows OS. You do not have to run a 32 bit Linux OS.

Edit: As a general rule of thumb, 64 bit can run any 32 bit